# RBF Kernel on Masked array

Tags: numpy, scikit-learn, mask, masked-array

I wonder if there is a way to compute the Gaussian kernel of a numpy masked array?

I import:

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import rbf_kernel
```

If one uses a masked array and gives it as the input to the `rbf_kernel` function of scikit learn package the result is not a masked array. It seems that all the pairwise distances are calculated regardless of some of them being masked!

Answer (score 4):

Scikit-learn doesn't support masked arrays.
Computing the RBF kernel is really simple if you can compute euclidean distances, though.